# Pythonic methods of returning the longest word in a string

Tags: python, string, function, string-length

I understand finding the longest word within a string has been asked and answered numerous times but I would like to know the difference between the following methods, and why one would use approach A over approach B, or vice versa.

**Approach A**

```
def LongestWord(sen):
  lw = ''
  w = ''
  for c in sen:
    if c.isalpha():
      w += c
    else:
      if len(w) > len(lw):
        lw = w
      w = ''
  if len(w) > len(lw):
    lw = w
  return lw
```

**VS Approach B**

```
def LongestWord(sen): 
  x = max(sen.split(), key=len)
  return x
```

Again, my goal is to inquire which method would be more stable, for a lack of better choice of words, and why. If you have your own alternative, please post it along with your explanation. Thank you!

Comment: Approach A uses terrible variable names and is hard to understand. Approach B is fairly obvious, making use of well-known, built-in functions. A uses `+=` repeatedly on strings, which is inefficient, and probably calls `len()` more than necessary too. That doesn’t really matter until they do the same thing, though, which they don’t. A includes no punctuation in its words (“you’re” being a perfectly fine word, for example) and B includes all punctuation (periods generally not being included in word length, for example).

Comment: Less code is better unless uncomprehensible. Since `B` is easily understood, and `A` is less so... But minitech is right about the punctuation char handling.

Comment: Don't hesitate to use longer variable names. You're not wasting any ink :)

Comment: note that for convention in Python functions should start lowercase

Comment: @minitech, thanks that was very thorough. Precisley what I was looking for. Also, thanks for the tips guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different reasons.
The most important is that, as a software developer, you must use the easiest, most comprehensible way to write a function.
Approach B is neat, concise, and easy to understand. Approach A is too complicated to understand: without knowing the name of the function it would be hard to even know what does it do.

This point us to a different aspect: code that is too hard to read is too hard to debug. Is Approach B correct? At a glance, yes. Is Approach A correct? It's hard to understand. We may write a test to see if both functions work (and we should do it) but if a function happens to not work, it would be way easier to debug Approach B than Approach A.

Last but not least, Approach B is 10 times faster

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import timeit

    print(timeit.timeit("LongestWordA('hello this is just an example')", number=1000, setup="from __main__ import LongestWordA"))
    print(timeit.timeit("LongestWordB('hello this is just an example')", number=1000, setup="from __main__ import LongestWordB"))

    # LongestWordA 0.013688346021808684
    # LongestWordB 0.004950157948769629
```

Comment: Suffice it to say, your the man! The **timeit** will come in handy in future pythonic endeavors. Thanks ;)

Comment: I'd leave out the last part regarding your timing results.  It's anecdotal at best... and remember Knuth: "Premature optimization is the root of all evil".

Answer (score 0):

When I look at the second approach, I can see what is going on immediately -- a string is split on consecutive runs of whitespace and then the longest substring is returned.

When I look at the first approach, it takes a lot more work to figure out what is going on.

The point is that python provides really powerful utilities for doing these kinds of simple tasks -- it makes the code easier to write, easier to read, less error prone, etc, etc.  Learning to use the common idioms and functions to your advantage is (IMHO) the essence of being "pythonic"

Comment: Thanks! I'll look more into it.

Answer (score 0):

First off, the second method is very readable, while the first is not. The method obviously (with knowledge of the max method) does what the name of the function says. Writing readable code is my favorite part about Python.

Second, the first method assumes responsibility for defining what a word is. The section

```
for c in sen:
  if c.isalpha():
    w += c
```

Will make `2spooky4me` shorter than `spookytoo`, because `LongestWord` doesn't count single integer characters as part of the word `(ex. '2'.isalpha() == False)`. This could be unexpected behavior to someone using this code.

Finally, the second example uses Pythons built-in methods more elegantly (ex. features of max instead of just len and binary operators), which I believe to be a big goal for the design of the language.

Answer (score 0):

**Approach B** is better by a longshot.  Approach A is confusing to follow, with all of the nested logic and terse variable names.

[PEP 20]:

- Beautiful is better than ugly.
- Readability counts.
- If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.

  `$ python -c "import this"`

Comment: "Flat is better than nested" would be appropriate as well i'm assuming. haha